# Brown leaves on strawberries

Tags: strawberries

We did not mulch our strawberries this winter and we have brown leaves on some of the plants. Do we take the brown leaves off?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if they're dead, but if your winter is not over yet, wait till the weather warms up - the dead leaves may provide some protection if the weather is still cold.

Comment: Good call Bamboo.  I always save cleaning up debris and top growth of perennials for spring to allow dead debris for protection during the winter.  Depending on their zone, those strawberries will be busting up through the soil very vigorous very alive.  Hey, I'm in zone 1b.  My strawberries have come back consistently for 4 years in a row...